# Is there a METABASE-like data visualization tool with time-series feature?

Tags: business-intelligence, metabase, kpi

We use Metabase to monitor our KPIs, such as total current active items.
It's a great tool, but when we needed to look at timely trends such as total current active items change by day.
Metabase can't help much, since it only displays what current database has.

I know there are many datawarehousing stacks I can use to store time-series data.
But just curious if there's any framework that can provide a framework to store time-series data of configured KPIs?

What I imagined is like an advanced metabse, the user scenario would be like this:

1. I can setup metrics I'd like to trace (like DAU, Total Active Items)
2. The framework automatically saves these metrics by specified time-slot (day, minute, week, month, on user's configuration)
3. Visualize these data

Would like to have some inputs and thought :D

Comment: I have been looking a fair bit for a similar tool for some time now. I found Grafana ,Splunk and Apache to be pretty useful. All three satisfy most of your requirements though I found Splunk to be more user friendly

Comment: @bharath I have experiences with grafana & apache superset (I'm guessing this is what you mean), they're both easy to use but lack of time-series recording ability. Not sure if splunk provides this? I've just create an trial account and exploring it, seems very powerful yet complex as well.